# Create a seperate stop commnad that can be used to break a loop in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am currently trying to code a quiz bot in discord, and right now I am having trouble trying to create a command that can be used to stop a session. This is what I've come up with so far:

```
@client.command()
async def ask(ctx):

    quiz_data = {
        'question_1': (["1", "one"], "one"),
        'question_2': (["2", "two"], "two"),
    }
    question = random.choice(list(quiz_data.keys()))
    answers, hint = quiz_data[question]

    await ctx.send("What is the answer to this question?")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(question)

    def check_sender(msg): 
        return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel

    def check_answer(msg):
        return any(answer in msg.content.lower() for answer in answers)
    try:
        async with timeout(10):
            while True:
                def running(self):
                    return True
                msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check_sender)
                if check_answer(msg):
                    await ctx.send("good")
                    break
                else:
                    print('someone got it wrong lol')
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send(f"What is the answer to this question? hint: {hint}")
        await ctx.send(question)

        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check_sender)
        if check_answer(msg):
            await ctx.send("good")
        else:
            await ctx.send("wrong.")


@client.command()
async def stopg(ctx):
    if running() == True:
        await ctx.send("Round is stopping...")
    else: 
        await ctx.send("No round active")
```

The command `stopg` does not work at the moment simply because `running` is only defined in the previous command. This is the attempt I decided to use cause I think this can explain what I want to accomplish the easiest; Create an indicator that can tell whether the loop or command is running or not, which will be applied as an if statement in the stop command. I honestly haven't done as much research about this since this just stormed into me a few days ago.

Sorry if this didn't make much sense, i'll be willing to answer any questions. Or any other way if what I mentioned is overcomplicating things. Thanks so much~.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing a `while True` you could do something like `while someVariable` then program the stop function to change the value of the variable `someVariable`. And then you could also check whether the loop is running or not by checking the variable `someVariable` itself.

Cheers,

Comment: i would like to add that OP needs to use a global variable to do this

Comment: Correct but to be specific @xcodz-dot means the variable "someVariable" needs to be global, so it can be accessed in both functions.

Comment: Thanks @pThreadMutex and the rest, but i'm not sure how that would look like. I've been trying it myself but the variable seems to change only after the timeout. I think i'm mssing something  but i'm not sure what it is. Thanks!